# Display a Link when the timer ends

Tags: jquery

I've put a timer and I want when the timer ends the webpage would display a link along with a message “This offer has expired. Subscribe to be notified when we have this offer again or Click this button  to take advantage of our other offers”.

```
<script>
function doneHandler(result) {

  var output = "This offer has expired. Subscribe to be notified when we have this offer again or Click the button below to take advantage of our other offers"

  alert(output);
}
var myCountdownTest = new Countdown({
                  time: 3,
                  width : 300, 
                  height  : 50,
                  onComplete : doneHandler
                  });
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're experiencing with the above code?

Comment: why don't you use a setTimeout() or a setInterval()

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ndjddysw/1/

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
      // Do something after 2 seconds
}, 2000);

Comment: I want to use setTimeout when the countdown ends. How will i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
<body>

   <!-- all your other HTML -->

   <div id="subscribeOffer" style="display: none;">
       <h3>This offer has expired!</h3>
       <p>
           Subscribe to be notified when we have this offer again or 
           <a href="http://somewhere.com">click here</a>
           to take advantage of our other offers.
       </p>
   </div>

   <script>

       function doneHandler ( result ) 
       {
           // If you are using just plain JavaScript, you would do:
           document.getElementById("subscribeOffer").style.display = "block";

          // or if you have jQuery, comment out the above and uncomment the below:
          // $("#subscribeOffer").show();
        }

        var myCountdownTest = new Countdown
        ({
            time: 3,
            width: 300, 
            height: 50,
            onComplete: doneHandler
        });

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: I want when the timer ends the webpage would display a link along with a message. How will I put anchor link in donehandler function?

Comment: Are you saying you are just wanting your "alert" to actually be HTML that contains a link?

Comment: Yes exactly! Please help me!

Comment: You simply need a DIV with your content in it and set it to `display: none;` and then when your timer ends set it to `display: block;`

Comment: I really don't see how adding another interval timer on top of a countdown timer already in place answers the question. OP doesn't ask about how to create another delay

Comment: I dont know jquery. Would you please explain the full code? I;ll be gratefull to you!

Comment: @charlietfl - yes ... we are figuring out what the OP actually wanted.

Comment: Right but your answer is based on comments that made no sense either within context of the question

Comment: @charlietfl - Nothing made sense. I'm in the middle of editing the answer. thanks.

Comment: Actually I don't know anything about jquery. If I want to call a html element in donehandler function what'll be the code? Would you guys please help me??

Comment: I updated the answer to give you an idea.  It includes jQuery and plain JavaScript answers.

Comment: No problem at all ... glad we could get you on the right track!